# Query for retrieving top two rows from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `Employee` with the following fields:

- EmpID
- Salary
- Name

I want to get top two employees with maximum salary.  How do I write this query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2000+:

```
  SELECT TOP 2
         e.*
    FROM EMPLOYEE e
ORDER BY e.salary DESC
```

MySQL & Postgres:

```
  SELECT e.*
    FROM EMPLOYEE e
ORDER BY e.salary DESC
   LIMIT 2
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT e.*,
               ROWNUM as rn
          FROM EMPLOYEE e
      ORDER BY e.salary DESC) x
 WHERE x.rn <= 2
```

- [Oracle: ROW_NUMBER vs ROWNUM](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
SELECT * from Employee  order by Salary  desc limit 2 ;
```

Comment: Or, if using SqlServer, _select top 2 * from employees order by salary_.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC;

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this.

SELECT TOP 2 EmpID,Salary,Name FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
With NumberedItems As
    (
    Select EmpId, Salary, Name
        , Row_Number() Over ( Order By Salary Desc ) As SalaryRank 
    From Employee
    )
Select EmpId, Salary, Name
From NumberedItems
Where SalaryRank <= 2
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` (CTE too) is SQL Server 2005+

Comment: Although technically the OP did not specify the version of SQL. Technically, it could have been SQL Server 4.2 in which the TOP command would not exist. ;)